# Clustering adjacent points in 2D

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis

I need to find all clusters of adjacent white points in a binary image. By term "adjacent" I mean that coordinates of two points differ by no more than 1 (i.e. the points `{0,0}` and `{1,1}` are adjacent). How to do this in *Mathematica* efficiently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In version 7 and 8 you have `MorphologicalComponents` which can do this. Its default `Method` (version 8) is "Connected" with 8 point connectivity being the default (you can switch this off with the option `CornerNeighbors->False`). So, this seems ideally suited to your requirements.

An example from the `MorphologicalComponents` doc page:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: serves me right for starting to implement flood fill in mathematica before reading the docs...

Comment: @acl ;-) Useful for v6 and earlier.

Comment: @Sjoerd +1. You (and the creators of the Documentation) forgot to mention that the target clusters of points must be white on black background. My original image is negate of this and this is the reason why my first attempts to use `MorphologicalComponents` failed.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Just use `ColorNegate` to invert the image.